# Camera projection for lines orthogonal to camera z-axis

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, projection-matrix

I'm working on an object tracking application using openCV.  I want to convert my pixel coordinates to world coordinates to get more meaningful information.  I have read a lot about computing the perspective transform matrix, and I know about cv2.solvePnP.  But I feel like my case should be special, because I'm tracking a runner on a track and field runway with the runway orthogonal to the camera's z-axis.  I will set up the camera to ensure this.

If I just pick two points on the runway edge, I can calculate a linear conversion from pixels to world coords at that specific height (ground level) and distance from the camera (i.e. along that line). Then I reason that the runner will run on a line parallel to the runway at a different height and slightly different distance from the camera, but the lines should still be parallel in the image, because they will both be orthogonal to the camera z-axis.  With all those constraints, I feel like I shouldn't need the normal number of points to track the runner on that particular axis.  My gut says that 2-3 should be enough.  Can anyone help me nail down the method here?  Am I completely off track?  With both height and distance from camera essentially fixed, shouldn't I be able to work with a much smaller set of correspondences?

Thanks, Bill

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I've answered this one myself.  It's true that only two correspondence points are needed given the following assumptions.

Assume:

1. World coordinates are set up with X-axis and Y-axis parallel to the ground plane.  X-axis is parallel to the runway.
2. Camera is translated and possibly rotated about X-axis (angled downward), but no rotation around Y-axis(camera plane parallel to runway and x-axis) or Z-axis (camera is level with respect to ground).
3. Camera intrinsic parameters are known from camera calibration.

Method:

1. Pick two points in the ground plane with known coordinates in world and image.  For example, two points on the runway edge as mentioned in original post.  The line connecting the poitns in world coordinates should not be parallel with either X or Z axis.
2. Since Y=0 for these points, ignore the second column of the rotation/translation matrix, reducing the projection to a planar homography transform (3x3 matrix).  Now we have 9 degrees of freedom.
3. The rotation assumptions will enforce a certain form on the rotation/translation matrix.  Namely, the first column and first row will be the identity (1,0,0).  This further reduces the number of degrees of freedom in the matrix to 5.
4. Constrain the values of the second column of the matrix such that cos^2(theta)+sin^2(theta) = 1.  This reduces the number of unknowns to only 4. Two correspondence points will give us the 4 equations we need to calculate the homography matrix for the ground plane.
5. Factor out the camera intrinsic parameter matrix from the homography matrix, leaving the rotation/translation matrix for the ground plane.
6. Due to the rotation assumptions made earlier, the ignored column of the rotation/translation matrix can be easily constructed from the third column of the same matrix, which is the second column in the ground plane homography matrix.
7. Multiply back out with the camera intrinsic parameters to arrive at the final universal projection matrix (from only 2 correspondence points!)

My test implentation has worked quite well.  Of course, it's sensitive to the accuracy of the two correspondence points provided, but that's kind of a given.